# Sync state of two NSMenuItems

Tags: objective-c, synchronization, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I have two `NSMenus` with the same `NSMenuItems`. Only one `NSMenuItem` in its `NSMenu` should be selected. (Kind of like an `NSMatrix`). So I connected each `NSMenuItem` to the same action and added an iVar for the index of the item with the `NSOnState`. Inside the method I set the state of the item with the old index to `NSOffState` and the new one to `NSOnState`, then I set the old index to the new index. This works just fine for one of the two `NSMenus`. But I would like to sync them both. I can add IBOutlets for every NSMenu and then set the states inside the method since I have access to both `NSMenus`. But this feels kind of redundant.. **Note:** I'm also planning to save the index in the user defaults so maybe it can be achieved by an `NSUserDefaultsController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I think I'll just code everything myself without bindings etc.